# Port game from iOS (iPad) to Windows

Tags: ios, windows, porting

Is it possible to to port a game, originally built for iOS (iPad version only, but it's not important) to Windows in an easy manner?

I assume I have all the source code of the original game. I also have experience with Obj C as well as with C#.

If not, what would be the steps for this kind of sorcery? Where could I find appropriate tutorials or references? Or anything.

Comment: That highly depends on the technology used to make the game! What frameworks did you use, what language?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did it, it was from the ground up. I was able to use my objective c classes as guides, but I still had to write it line by line **(nothing automatic)**.

There is, however, a good introduction to the differences from an iOS developer's perspective over on Jesse Liberty's site that I found helpful: http://jesseliberty.com/2010/08/23/i2w-an-iphone-developers-guide-to-creating-windows-phone-7-applications-tutorial/

Comment: Thanx for reply, that's what i thought. I have "ported" an Android app to iOS. I've done both of the apps myself, and i could use java classes as guides, but there was still a lot of work and nothing is straight-forward, especially if you want to maintain the way user uses it's base OS.